# Force coerce pandas dataframe column to int64 type

Tags: python, pandas

I am dealing with terabytes of mildly noisy data broken up into ~20 GB dataframes. Maybe 20 in each 2 million rows has bad data in certain columns. I want a quick forced type casting of a pandas data frame column to `int`, nulling out`(NaN)` ONLY THE VALUES that can't be forced to an `int` (don't null out the entire row)

Using `pd.to_numeric(df, errors='coerce')` I have been able to remove the strings. My problem is then using `.astype(pd.Int64Dtype())`.

This has given errors multiple times

```
"TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64"
```

- once due to the existence of a 0.5  and the other due to the existence of a 21 digit code which is above Int64 capacity.

What is the most efficient way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `downcast` argument:

`df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce', downcast='integer')`

Comment: Unfortunately downcast only works after the numeric casting is already done, and the 'coerce' errors value doesn't carry over. If the entire column is of the form ['624.0', 'Big Bang', '23.0'], the code you provided accurately converts it to [624,<NaN>,23].

The problem is my data is like: 
['624.0','Bang', '0.5', '2.3012 e+30']. Your code accurately converts '624.0' to 624.0 and nulls out the string 'Bang'. But once it converts to numeric, it doesnt further downcast to int because 2301200000....0000 and 0.5 cannot be faithfully converted to an integer, and the 'coerce' no longer applies